# How to implement autocompletion in a modal? (Ruby/JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, google-places-api, simple-form-for

I am willing to create a new client from my client#index. This works properly while clicking the "Add a client" button and filling in the asked information (name, address, mail, phone_number).

I would like to implement autocompletion with Google Maps on the address. I used Google's Places API Web Service in order to do so.

1 - I enabled the Places API in the Library in my Google Developer's console

2 - I activated the address autocomplete on the input with the client_address id and exported the function with the following code:

```
 function autocomplete() {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var clientAddress = document.querySelector(".client_address").lastChild;

    if (clientAddress) {
      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(clientAddress, { types: [ 'geocode' ] });
      console.log("please autocomplete")
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(clientAddress, 'keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.key === "Enter") {
          e.preventDefault(); // Do not submit the form on Enter.
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

export { autocomplete };
```

3 - I imported the function and called it from the map JavaScript pack with the following code:

```
import GMaps from 'gmaps/gmaps.js';
import { autocomplete } from '../components/autocomplete';

console.log('Hello World from Webpacker 2')

const mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
if (mapElement) { // don't try to build a map if there's no div#map to inject in
  const map = new GMaps({ el: '#map', lat: 0, lng: 0 });
  const markers = JSON.parse(mapElement.dataset.markers);
  map.addMarkers(markers);
  if (markers.length === 0) {
    map.setZoom(2);
  } else if (markers.length === 1) {
    map.setCenter(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng);
    map.setZoom(14);
  } else {
    map.fitLatLngBounds(markers);
  }
}
autocomplete();
```

4 - If I inspect the input field of my client_address, this is what I get:

```
<input class="form-control string required" id="client_address" type="text" name="client[address]" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="off">
```

5 - In case needed, this is my simple-form-for

```
<%= simple_form_for(@client) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <% if @client.errors.any? %>
    <div class="errors-container">
      <ul>
        <% @client.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :address, wrapper_html: { id: "client_address" }, input_html: { id: "client_address" }, class: "awesomeplete" %>
    <%= f.input :mail %>
    <%= f.input :phone_number %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Could someone explain why autocomplete="off" and how could I, in my modal, make it work properly based on Google's Places API Web Service?

Thanks for your help!

Max

Comment: the `autocomplete="off"` bit in that markup is the browser autocomplete and not the google places API autocomplete.  you know those suggestions you get when you fill up a form with your name or mobile number? That's the browser autocomplete.  That's what's being turned off.  The google places js adds that bit so that the browser autocomplete won't get in the way when address results are shown when you start typing.  If it's not giving out a list of address, that will be caused by a different thing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I totally see what you mean and didn't now it was the browser's one. Any ideas about what I am doing wrong here that makes that the list of addresses is not being displayed?